# Перезагрузка страницы Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Сделал роутинг на Angular, работает все хорошо, кроме перезагрузки страницы, когда уже прошел по какой-нибудь ссылке и состояние обновилось.

Т.е., на сервер URI уходит другой, и, соответсвенно, по данному обновленному пути нет ресурса.

В Angular есть какое-то готовое решение, чтобы не писать роутинг на сервере?

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, полный, воспроизводимый пример](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: я думаю, кто работал с Ангуляром сразу поймут о чем я пишу, а тем кто нет, зачем вдаваться в подробности вопроса

Comment: без вашего кода - нельзя сказать где именно у вас ошибка

Comment: @Grundy, всё понятно в вопросе.

Comment: @Qwertiy, кроме того что за сервер :-)

Comment: @Grundy, это не помешает словесно описать, что должен делать сервер. Так даже полезнее будет - и применимость к любому серверу есть и разбираться в том, что делают настройки конкретного сервера не надо.

Comment: сервер всмысле свой локальный

Comment: @ruslik, речь о технологии, а не адресе.

Comment: @Qwertiy, добавишь ответ?:)

Comment: @Grundy, я не совсем уверен в том, что написать. Есть идея про редирект и про запись с переходом на самой странице. Не уверен, будет ли редирект с хешом корректно обработан - надо проверять.

Comment: @Qwertiy, Ну вообще сервер просто **всегда** должен возвращать индексную страницу по любому запросу, а дальше ангуляр сам разберется

Comment: @Grundy, ой.. Да, понял. Хорошая идея, хотя тогда кэширование не очень удачно будет работать.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну почему? просто кэшировать надо будет не только основную страницу но и те которые по запросам получаются

Comment: @Grundy, я это и назвал - не очень удачно - при каждом обновлении с новым url адрес будет новым, т. е. страница запросится с сервера. А браузерный кэш забивается не слишком полезными данными.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35121/discussion-between-grundy-and-qwertiy).

Answer (score 1):

Если используете html5 node, (соответственно в урл нет решетки '#'), то  думаю никак без роутинга на сервере не обойтись.

Answer (score 0):

Настройте ваш сервер на отдачу по любому запросу `index.html` и тогда весь роутинг будет на `AngularJS`. Если у вас еще есть ресурсы по этому же домену, добавьте исключения в конфиг сервера.

Comment: так если отдавать index.html, то всегда будет загружаться начало приложения

Comment: получатся надо как то хранить последнее состояние

Comment: А вот состояние хранится в url и управляется angular route. Его нужно "применить" при загрузке страницы.

Comment: И аккуратненько не уйти в рекурсию: применил состояние -> обновил url -> применил состояние ->... :)

Comment: @ruslik зачем? У вас состояние будет хранится в url. То есть index.html отдаемся по любому url. А при загрузке приложения ва роутинг как раз и понимает что нужно отобразить

Comment: понял, спасибо за объяснение